# Do we need to add Junit dependency with "karate-core" to run the tests in parallel?

Tags: karate

I am a little confused while reading [Karate Framework official documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution).

1. I have created a Maven karate project just by adding a karate-core dependency.
2. Added some feature files.
3. I want to run all feature files.

The Karate GitHub page mentioned that "Karate can run tests in parallel, and dramatically cut down execution time. This is a 'core' feature and does not depend on JUnit, Maven or Gradle."

I tried to create a class as mentioned in [Parallel Execution](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#junit-5-parallel-execution) with the assumption that Junit will be included in core dependency as mentioned in the above paragraph (This is a 'core' feature and does not depend on JUnit, Maven or Gradle.). But it is not able to resolve Junit imports and I don't even see karate-core including Junit dependency.

Am I understanding the statement correctly? Do I need to add Jupiter Junit dependency explicitly?

I am aware of running feature files using Runner class from a main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `karate-core` and then want to resolve JUnit imports, you have to either:

- switch to using the `karate-junit5` dependency (it will bring `karate-core` as a dependency)
- or add the jupiter junit dependencies yourself

Teams typically choose option 1 since it is simpler. It may be more convenient for you to use the [`karate-template`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-template) as a reference.

When we say "does not depend on JUnit, Maven or Gradle" - it refers to the `Runner` API. That API does not need JUnit and can be run from a Java "main" method if you really want. If you want to use JUnit assertions (which means JUnit imports are needed), that's your choice.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I misunderstood the statement. Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Comment: @AMODMAHAJAN thank you for the feedback, I have edited the docs to try to be more clear: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#junit-5-parallel-execution